# Proprietary DBX File Type

Tags: database, file-type, dbx

I am trying to mine data out of a .dbx file.  This file is NOT associated with Microsoft Outlook Express.  It is for a Laboratory Information Management System.  Unfortunately their project management skills aren't the best and getting patches/updates are not the easiest.  The central file repository consists of .dbx files for each study we do.  On the client side a local database is created and the user updates these files each time.  I've had issues with studies conflicting and throwing CException errors but the company has yet to come up with a fix.  I just need to mine the file for the tables that are in it and subsequent data it has.

Any suggestions,
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"dbx" is probably a Visual Foxpro table.  You *might* be able to read it with Microsoft Access or Microsoft Excel. (Or, of course, with Microsoft Visual Foxpro.)

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Not it's not probably a Visual FoxPro table.